# i am trying to show JSON array using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show JSON Array on UI. JSON array is in the controller and i am trying to get them on view. I have mentioned the code what I have done. 
Could any of the gurus kindly ponder over this question and answer/give feedback if my dirty hack is the right way or it can be better implemented. 
Here is code.

```js
var practiceApp = angular.module('usermodel', [])
.controller('UserController', UserController);

function UserController(){
 this.users= [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
    "username": "Kamren",
    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    "address": {
      "street": "Skiles Walks",
      "suite": "Suite 351",
      "city": "Roscoeview",
      "zipcode": "33263",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-31.8129",
        "lng": "62.5342"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "demarco.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Keebler LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    "address": {
      "street": "Norberto Crossing",
      "suite": "Apt. 950",
      "city": "South Christy",
      "zipcode": "23505-1337",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-71.4197",
        "lng": "71.7478"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "ola.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Considine-Lockman",
      "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rex Trail",
      "suite": "Suite 280",
      "city": "Howemouth",
      "zipcode": "58804-1099",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.8918",
        "lng": "21.8984"
      }
    },
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "elvis.io",
    "company": {
      "name": "Johns Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    "address": {
      "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
      "suite": "Suite 729",
      "city": "Aliyaview",
      "zipcode": "45169",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-14.3990",
        "lng": "-120.7677"
      }
    },
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "jacynthe.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Abernathy Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
      "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Glenna Reichert",
    "username": "Delphine",
    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    "address": {
      "street": "Dayna Park",
      "suite": "Suite 449",
      "city": "Bartholomebury",
      "zipcode": "76495-3109",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.6463",
        "lng": "-168.8889"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "conrad.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Yost and Sons",
      "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
      "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
    "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
    "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
      "suite": "Suite 198",
      "city": "Lebsackbury",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ambrose.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Hoeger LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
]
}
```

```html
<h1> Here we have listed two users</h1>
<body>
<div ng-model="usermodel" ng-controller="UserController as us" >
<table class="table table-striped">
 <th>id</th>
 <th>name</th>
 <th>email</th>
 <th>address</th>
 <th>phone</th>
 </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat= "item inusers">
     <td>{{item.id}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.email}}</td>
     <td>{{item.address.city}}</td>
     <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="user/userController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
I will be thankful for the great help.
cheer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution working. Hope it helps :)

```js
var App = angular.module('App', [])

  App.controller('UserController', function($scope) {

    setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.$apply(function(){ 
        $scope.Users = [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Leanne Graham",
          "username": "Bret",
          "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
          "address": {
            "street": "Kulas Light",
            "suite": "Apt. 556",
            "city": "Gwenborough",
            "zipcode": "92998-3874",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-37.3159",
              "lng": "81.1496"
            }
          },
          "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
          "website": "hildegard.org",
          "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Ervin Howell",
          "username": "Antonette",
          "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
          "address": {
            "street": "Victor Plains",
            "suite": "Suite 879",
            "city": "Wisokyburgh",
            "zipcode": "90566-7771",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-43.9509",
              "lng": "-34.4618"
            }
          },
          "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
          "website": "anastasia.net",
          "company": {
            "name": "Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Clementine Bauch",
          "username": "Samantha",
          "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
          "address": {
            "street": "Douglas Extension",
            "suite": "Suite 847",
            "city": "McKenziehaven",
            "zipcode": "59590-4157",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-68.6102",
              "lng": "-47.0653"
            }
          },
          "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
          "website": "ramiro.info",
          "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
            "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
            "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
          "username": "Karianne",
          "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
          "address": {
            "street": "Hoeger Mall",
            "suite": "Apt. 692",
            "city": "South Elvis",
            "zipcode": "53919-4257",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "29.4572",
              "lng": "-164.2990"
            }
          },
          "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
          "website": "kale.biz",
          "company": {
            "name": "Robel-Corkery",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
            "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
          "username": "Kamren",
          "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
          "address": {
            "street": "Skiles Walks",
            "suite": "Suite 351",
            "city": "Roscoeview",
            "zipcode": "33263",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-31.8129",
              "lng": "62.5342"
            }
          },
          "phone": "(254)954-1289",
          "website": "demarco.info",
          "company": {
            "name": "Keebler LLC",
            "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
            "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
          "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
          "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
          "address": {
            "street": "Norberto Crossing",
            "suite": "Apt. 950",
            "city": "South Christy",
            "zipcode": "23505-1337",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-71.4197",
              "lng": "71.7478"
            }
          },
          "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
          "website": "ola.org",
          "company": {
            "name": "Considine-Lockman",
            "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
            "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
          "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
          "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
          "address": {
            "street": "Rex Trail",
            "suite": "Suite 280",
            "city": "Howemouth",
            "zipcode": "58804-1099",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "24.8918",
              "lng": "21.8984"
            }
          },
          "phone": "210.067.6132",
          "website": "elvis.io",
          "company": {
            "name": "Johns Group",
            "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
            "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
          "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
          "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
          "address": {
            "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
            "suite": "Suite 729",
            "city": "Aliyaview",
            "zipcode": "45169",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-14.3990",
              "lng": "-120.7677"
            }
          },
          "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
          "website": "jacynthe.com",
          "company": {
            "name": "Abernathy Group",
            "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
            "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Glenna Reichert",
          "username": "Delphine",
          "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
          "address": {
            "street": "Dayna Park",
            "suite": "Suite 449",
            "city": "Bartholomebury",
            "zipcode": "76495-3109",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "24.6463",
              "lng": "-168.8889"
            }
          },
          "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
          "website": "conrad.com",
          "company": {
            "name": "Yost and Sons",
            "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
            "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
          "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
          "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
          "address": {
            "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
            "suite": "Suite 198",
            "city": "Lebsackbury",
            "zipcode": "31428-2261",
            "geo": {
              "lat": "-38.2386",
              "lng": "57.2232"
            }
          },
          "phone": "024-648-3804",
          "website": "ambrose.net",
          "company": {
            "name": "Hoeger LLC",
            "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
            "bs": "target end-to-end models"
          }
        }
        ]

      });
},100);

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="App" ng-controller="UserController">

    <table class=" table table-striped table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Id
        </td>
        <td>
          Name 
        </td>
        <td>
          Email
        </td>
        <td>
          Address
        </td>
        <td>
          Phone Number
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr  ng-repeat="item in Users">
        <td>{{ item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.phone }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tr ng-repeat= "item inusers">`
Should be 
`<tr ng-repeat= "item in us.users">`

Answer (score 0):

Brother,sorry but there's a lot of erros on your code.

I made some changes on your code and now is right.

```js
var practiceApp = angular.module('usermodel', [])
.controller('UserController', ['$scope',function($scope){
  
  var self = this;
  
  self.users = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
    "username": "Kamren",
    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    "address": {
      "street": "Skiles Walks",
      "suite": "Suite 351",
      "city": "Roscoeview",
      "zipcode": "33263",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-31.8129",
        "lng": "62.5342"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "demarco.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Keebler LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    "address": {
      "street": "Norberto Crossing",
      "suite": "Apt. 950",
      "city": "South Christy",
      "zipcode": "23505-1337",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-71.4197",
        "lng": "71.7478"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "ola.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Considine-Lockman",
      "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rex Trail",
      "suite": "Suite 280",
      "city": "Howemouth",
      "zipcode": "58804-1099",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.8918",
        "lng": "21.8984"
      }
    },
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "elvis.io",
    "company": {
      "name": "Johns Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    "address": {
      "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
      "suite": "Suite 729",
      "city": "Aliyaview",
      "zipcode": "45169",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-14.3990",
        "lng": "-120.7677"
      }
    },
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "jacynthe.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Abernathy Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
      "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Glenna Reichert",
    "username": "Delphine",
    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    "address": {
      "street": "Dayna Park",
      "suite": "Suite 449",
      "city": "Bartholomebury",
      "zipcode": "76495-3109",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.6463",
        "lng": "-168.8889"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "conrad.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Yost and Sons",
      "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
      "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
    "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
    "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
      "suite": "Suite 198",
      "city": "Lebsackbury",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ambrose.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Hoeger LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
]
  
}]);
```

```html
<h1> Here we have listed two users</h1>
<body>
<div ng-app="usermodel" ng-controller="UserController as us" >
<table class="table table-striped">
 <th>id</th>
 <th>name</th>
 <th>email</th>
 <th>address</th>
 <th>phone</th>
 </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat= "item in us.users">
     <td>{{item.id}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.email}}</td>
     <td>{{item.address.city}}</td>
     <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="user/userController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you brother. it works on this snippet but not on my code.